# How to programatically populate a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have been scratching my head for a while over this.

So I have added in design mode a `datagridview` to my form.

The datagridview has 2 columns, one column is textbox column, the other column is combobox column.

I have figured out how to programmatically populate the cells of a textbox, however I can't figure out which property to use to populate the combobox column.

I am simply looking to have a `dropdown` with 3 options. Any ideas would be great.

P.S: I just picked up VB.net 2 days ago so I apologize if the question is primitive :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `DataSource` in your combobox, you can do this

```
Dim dgvcc As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
With dgvcc
   .DataSource = answerStr
   .ValueMember = "CampaignAnswerId"
   .DisplayMember = "Answer"
End With

DataGridViewName.Item(columnIndex, rowIndex) = dgvcc
```

or you can just do this

```
Dim dgvcc As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
dgvcc.Items.Add("test1")
dgvcc.Items.Add("test2")
dgvcc.Items.Add("test3")

DataGridViewName.Item(columnIndex, rowIndex) = dgvcc
```

Take note that you have to do this while you loop inside the `DataGridView`.

```
For rowIndex as integer = 0 To DataGridViewName.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim dgvcc As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
    dgvcc.Items.Add("test1")
    dgvcc.Items.Add("test2")
    dgvcc.Items.Add("test3")

    DataGridViewName.Item(yourtextboxcolumnIndex, rowIndex) = dgvcc
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'Declare ComboBoxColumn
Dim cbColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
cbColumn.Name = "Column ComboBox"

'Add Values 
For value As Integer = 0 To 5
    cbColumn.Items.Add("Value = " & value.ToString)
Next

'Add ComboBox 
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cbColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this in the ***DataGridView_RowsAdded*** event

My code looks like this:

```
    Dim qualifierCell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell =
        DirectCast(gridAddTable.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(gtQualifier.Index), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
       'gridAddTable.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(gtQualifier.Index)
    For t As Int32 = 0 To tableMnemonics.Count - 1
        qualifierCell.Items.Add(tableMnemonics(t))
    Next
```

Notes:

You may have noticed my use of gtQualifier.Index.  I prefer using the actual name of the cell but you could also use Cell("gtQualifier") or just the index: Cell(0) in my case.

You can skip the  ***DirectCast*** call (using the commented code directly after it), but then **Visual Studio** will warn you about an implicit cast (no big deal)  In C# you need to explicitly cast because it does not do implicit casting.  You would write:

```
 (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)gridAddTable.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(gtQualifier.Index)
```

If you code this in the ***DataGridView_RowsAdded*** event,  you will need to make sure that tableMnemonics is populated prior to the call to ***InitializeComponents*** because InitializeComponents adds the first new row.  The InitializeComponents call is located in the ***New()*** subroutine in your ***.Designer*** file. (in C# ***New*** is in the FormName.cs file)

Alternatively, you could put this code in the ***UserAddedRow*** event.  In this case you would need to populate the first added row in your form's ***Load*** event.